# Unsuccessfully copying ~300GB VMDK file drive formatted as VMFS on Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, esxi, vmdk

Alright, I'm going to attempt to explain my situation thoroughly so bear with me. My current state is this. I have a 500GB HDD that used to be in a server - it hosted VMs - and was one of two drives in RAID 1. I'm assuming that both drives are identical at this point, but I have the other drive if for whatever reason this one isn't working, or I need to use it.

This drive is attached to a small linux box over onboard SATA (it's an Intel server MiniITX mobo) running Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS, freshly installed specifically for this purpose. I've installed `vmfs-tools`, giving access `vmfs-fuse`, which I am using as such to mount the drive:

`sudo vmfs-fuse /dev/sda1 /mnt/recovery`

This works successfully as a read-only mount (note that /dev/sdb is my boot drive, they're swapped cause I mixed up the SATA ports). My fdisk is as follows:

```
taylor@nas:~$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT.           Use GNU Parted.

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1   975699967   487849983+  ee  GPT
```

I can successfully read the contents of the folder containing my problematic file, `dot-flat.vmdk`:

```
taylor@nas:~$ sudo ls /mnt/recovery/dot
dot-flat.vmdk  dot.vmdk  dot.vmx   vmware-1.log  vmware-3.log  vmware.log
dot.nvram      dot.vmsd  dot.vmxf  vmware-2.log  vmware-4.log
```

Naturally wanting to test to make sure I can read the files properly, hoping that the contents weren't corrupted, I tried `tail`ing `vmware.log`:

```
taylor@nas:~$ sudo tail /mnt/recovery/dot/vmware.log
2014-12-01T09:19:46.553Z| vmx| I120: VMIOP: Exit
2014-12-01T09:19:46.696Z| vmx| I120: Vix: [35957 mainDispatch.c:849]: VMAutomation_LateShutdown()
2014-12-01T09:19:46.696Z| vmx| I120: Vix: [35957 mainDispatch.c:799]:  VMAutomationCloseListenerSocket. Closing listener socket. 
2014-12-01T09:19:46.715Z| vmx| I120: Flushing VMX VMDB connections
2014-12-01T09:19:46.715Z| vmx| I120: VmdbDbRemoveCnx: Removing Cnx from Db for '/db/connection/#1/'
2014-12-01T09:19:46.715Z| vmx| I120: VmdbCnxDisconnect: Disconnect: closed pipe for pub cnx '/db/connection/#1/' (0)
2014-12-01T09:19:46.721Z| vmx| I120: VMX exit (0).
2014-12-01T09:19:46.721Z| vmx| I120: AIOMGR-S : stat o=1 r=3 w=0 i=0 br=49152 bw=0
2014-12-01T09:19:46.721Z| vmx| I120: OBJLIB-LIB: ObjLib cleanup done.
2014-12-01T09:19:46.721Z| vmx| W110: VMX has left the building: 0.
```

So that works fine, it's probably not a drive issue. Either way, I wanted to check SMART data. The drive was working just fine before I pulled them to upgrade them. I installed `smartmontools` and then:

```
taylor@nas:~$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda
smartctl 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [x86_64-linux-3.13.0-32-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Western Digital RE3 Serial ATA
Device Model:     WDC WD5002ABYS-18B1B0
Serial Number:    WD-WCASY4933732
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 202b597b2
Add. Product Id:  DELL�
Firmware Version: 02.03B04
User Capacity:    500,107,862,016 bytes [500 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 2.5, 3.0 Gb/s
Local Time is:    Sun Dec  7 01:55:02 2014 PST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x84)    Offline data collection activity
                    was suspended by an interrupting command from host.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0)    The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:         ( 9480) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:              (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003)    Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01)    Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:      (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:      ( 112) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:      (   5) minutes.
SCT capabilities:            (0x303f)    SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   194   185   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       3291
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       196
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   056   056   000    Old_age   Always       -       32738
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       106
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       99
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       196
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   108   105   000    Old_age   Always       -       39
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     32447         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

To me at least, this looks like a pretty straight-forward SMART report for an old drive, especially for one with 32638 hours (1352 days!) of power-on time. I've run the report on the other drive (raid pair) before, and the results were pretty similar, if I recall correctly.

The drive in question contains about 8 VMs, all of which I had no problem pulling from the drive. To do this I used a simple `cp` command to a different drive and that was that. That target drive, the same that the OS is running on, has about 700GB free. The problem started once `cp` reached the biggest (by a huge margin) VMDK file out of all of them. Most of the VMDKs were around 25-30GB, whereas the problematic one is about 300GB. The large VMDK was originally created as a THICK VMDK. Here's what `cp` does:

```
taylor@nas:~$ sudo cp /mnt/recovery/dot/dot-flat.vmdk ~/dot-flat.vmdk
cp: error reading ‘/mnt/recovery/dot/dot-flat.vmdk’: Input/output error
cp: failed to extend ‘/home/taylor/dot-flat.vmdk’: Input/output error
```

Everything I read about the `Input/output error` deal meant the drive was failing. But I had the same problem on both drives, and the SMART test seemed alright, so I figure it might be something else. The file size could also be a factor.

So, I decided to try `rsync`, as a bit-for-bit copy might suit me better. This one is a bit stranger. At first it seemed that `rsync` was working great, I could `ls -al` the target directory and could see the temporary file size increasing steadily. However, once the target file hits the appropriate size, it shows the says `Input/output error` as before, and then starts the `rsync` process all over again, deleting the file that it just transferred (or at least partly). Talk about frustrating. Here's what that output looks like:

A little more than halfway through, going fine:

```
taylor@nas:~$ sudo rsync -av --progress /mnt/recovery/dot/dot-flat.vmdk ~/dot-flat.vmdk
sending incremental file list
dot-flat.vmdk
201,769,451,520  62%   95.50MB/s    0:20:30
```

And after completion:

```
taylor@nas:~$ sudo rsync -av --progress /mnt/recovery/dot/dot-flat.vmdk ~/dot-flat.vmdk
sending incremental file list
dot-flat.vmdk
322,122,547,200 100%   81.94MB/s    1:02:29 (xfr#1, to-chk=0/1)
rsync: read errors mapping "/mnt/recovery/dot/dot-flat.vmdk": Input/output error (5)
WARNING: dot-flat.vmdk failed verification -- update discarded (will try again).
dot-flat.vmdk
    672,759,808   0%   85.96MB/s    1:00:52
```

Really, in the end I'm after some files that are inside the VMDK. If there's a way to mount the VMDK directly, I'd love to know, but everything I've seen online on the topic doesn't work, most because I've got a VMFS volume instead of something more straight-forward like EXT4. I figured there may be a few workarounds, but I'm not quite sure

I figured I could try popping the two drives back in the server, recreating my ESXi VMs and pulling the data off that way? Nope. The server they were in is a Dell Poweredge 1950 with a SAS 6i/R RAID controller, which already has a different array on it. I couldn't pop the drives back in and load them up in ESXi if I wanted to, without formatting them at least.

So this is where I turn to SuperUser. Any suggestions as to what I could do? Any sort of alternative copy utility? A way to mount the VMDK given the drive is formatted as VMFS? A fix for my input/output errors? Maybe even ripping apart the VMDK manually? I had only a single partition on the image itself, so it would be pretty easy to guess where the given virtual EXT4 partition would start, but I don't know the first thing about how VMDK files are structured.

I appreciate your time reading!

Comment: You could install ESXi somewhere (no need to register, there’s a trial period) and try accessing the data with the “official” driver.

Comment: @DanielB I was trying to sleep last night and realized that this was still an option. I originally had ruled it out because I don't have the necessary spots on the server to do so, and if I pull the current drives out then my current raid array breaks. I'm going to install ESXi on another machine, probably the same one I used for these tests, and report back.

Comment: @DanielB Good news! It worked. I had to run ESXi off of a USB drive running on the server, because the NAS box I was going to use didn't support hardware virtualization, and only had 2GB RAM. Either way, I'm actively zipping up my data now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of work and a mind-jogging from @DanielB, I realized that I could just set up another ESXi instance on a USB drive on the server, install from scratch, attach the old drive to the SATA port that I used to run my ESXi host drive on, and then recreate the VM that way.

It booted straight up, read my files, and everything went smoothly.